# Regarding headphones

Tags: headphones

[image]i have a headphone. it it having problem while listining to music. it is having wheel like structure to increase music. the wheel like structure is having problems. when i press it little or roll it slightly then sound is good but it again stops. Please help me.

I m sorry that the question is off topic. I m not an eletrical engineer. i m a child of 16 who want to repair my headphone. i have got my answer by-Bimpelrekkie and see how i used cello tape insted of sodering-[image]

Comment: Simplest solution: solder left blue wire to right blue wire directly. Do same for green wire. Then the volume control will no longer work, you'll have to use some other volume control. If you cannot solder or do not have access to someone who can then just buy new headphones.

Comment: thanks for solution. but soldering is important?

Comment: can i join it like a wire?

Comment: Since you clearly have no experience repairing electronics, this question is off-topic for Stack Exchange.

Comment: i just want to fix it and hear my music

Comment: *can i join it like a wire?* Unclear what you mean, you came to an engineering site, we electrical engineers **solder** when we want a decent connection. We give you a hint, you do that. Your "I just want..." and questioning the provided solutions will not make you popular here.

Comment: i dont want to be popular, beside that, i have to join golden wire too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wheel is connected to the very small [potentiometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiometer) which basically controls how much of the power delivered from your player reaches the headphones.
The problem is that the potentiometers like these tend to degrade.
The solution would be to try disassemble the casing of the wheel and clean the internals with rubbing alcohol or something similar.
If it does not work another way is to remove the potentiometer and solder leads to bypass the regulation. Then you have no regulation, but the volume would be always at maximum.

Comment: please help me more

Comment: how to remove the potentiometre. i have no problem about max volume.